# Conditional probability from XYZ table

Tags: probability, self-study

Given this table, is X conditionally independent of Y give Z?

[image]

I know conditional independence is P(X|Y,Z) = P(X, Z), but I'm a bit confused about how I can use that with values from the table. I understand how to get P(X|Y,Z) from the table, but am a bit confused about the right hand side of the equation, for example P(X = 0, Z = 0) can have 2 values? I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question, so let me give you some hints so that you could solve it by yourself.

- The table shows the [joint probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) $\sum_{x,y,z} P(x, y, x) = 1$.
- Recall the definition of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

  $$
  P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
  $$

  it will be needed to compute the conditional probabilities from the joint probabilities.
- You also need the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

  $$
    P(A) = \sum_n P(A \cap B_n)
    $$

  to get the marginal probabilities.
- Use the above and check against the definition of [conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence)

  > $$ P(A|B,C) = P(A|C) $$
  >
  > [...] In this case, $A$ and $B$ are said to be conditionally
  > independent given $C$

Comment: Thanks! So I tried to calculate P(X = 0) = sum(P(X ^ Zn)) and got 11/18. This was from: P(x = 0, z = 0) + P(x = 0, z = 1) and this is 1/10 + 1/15 + 4/15 + 8/45 = 11/18. Is this the correct way to calculate? Same process for P(x = 1). I think I calculated P(X | Z) similarly

Comment: Thanks for all the help, it's been a long while since I've done this stuff so I'm kind of relearning a lot of it. Just to be clear, to get P(X | Z) i took the results from P(X ^ Z) and divided by P(Z = 0) = 1/3 and P(Z = 1) = 2/3, does that sound correct?

Comment: @user7538434 yes, basically for $P(X=1)$ you sum all the probabilities where $X=1$ i.e. $\sum_{y,z} P(X=1,Y=y,Z=z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post an answer of my question since I think I have the correct answer now in case others see this and think it's useful.

Following Tim's advice I calculated P(X|Z) and compared that to P(X|Y,Z) which I think is equivalent to P(X^Z)P(Y^Z)

so using the table in the original question:

P(X=0|Z=0) = P(X=0^Z=0)/P(Z=0) = (1/15 + 1/10) / (1/3) = 1/2
similarly:
P(X=1|Z=0) = P(X=1^Z=0)/P(Z=0) = 1/2
P(X=0|Z=1) = P(X=0^Z=1)/P(Z=1) = 2/3
P(X=1|Z=1) = P(X=1^Z=1)/P(Z=1) = 1/3

For X to be conditionally independent of Y given Z then P(Y^Z) should be 1, but we can see that it isn't. Therefore X isn't conditionally independent of Y give Z.

This also seems to just be clear when looking at the table, since we need to know the value of Y and Z to get X.